# Object Mapping Error - Java

Tags: java, dozer

I am trying to perform custom dozer mapping and see the below error -

> Expected : class [Lcom.customer.types.WorkListDetails;, Actual : class
>   com.customer.types.WorkListDetails

The class name seems to be the same but I don't understand what [L is.

Comment: Expected an array, actual just an instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class names are not the same; the code is expecting an array of `WorkListDetails` instances, but you are providing only a single instance. The `[` part means that the type is an array. The `L` specifies a class (and will end in a `;`). In this case, it specifies the type of the array.